# transfer objects which represent tables between client and server

Tags: c#, serialization, linq-to-sql, .net-remoting

I have remoting server with linq to sql generated file to handle db operations.

is it possible to make the partial class which represent a table serializable ?

also in traditional remotting solution, we create the Interface with serializable classes to be as shared library, then reference it by server code, and also reference it by client code.
so how to create a serializable classes from inner classes which represent tables in linq to sql class?

what other alternative ways to transfer an object which represent table row from client to server ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what something like JSON is for. You can serialize the object into JSON on the server and instantiate the object(or array of objects) on the client.

```
 {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Comment: thank you for replying however, this is not related to JSON, this is related to .Net Remoting issues by microsoft, I can make any object class transfereable by adding [Serializable] notation at class beginning, my question is how to do so with entity classes which represent db tables, these classes are generated automatically by linq to sql